Android Studio Emulator Proxy
I have problem with Proxyman. I use Proxyman with Android Studio Emulator (Windows 10) but sometimes with some requests to the network I get error such as:
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0x7dbbc4e8bed8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT (external/boringssl/src/crypto/cipher_extra/e_chacha20poly1305.c:259 0x7dba215d2112:0x00000000) error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:294 0x7dba215d2112:0x00000000) 
Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
